# How to split/move n subfolders from a main folder in linux?

Tags: linux

I have 100k sub folders with some files in it in a directory. I need to move 50k subfolder each to a new directory.

```
Main_Folder:
    subfolder1
    subfolder2
    ...
    ...
    ...
    subfolder199999
    subfolder200000
```

Expected is

```
Main_Folder_1:
    subfolder1
    subfolder2
    ...
    ...
    ...
    subfolder49999
    subfolder50000
```

```
Main_Folder_2:
    subfolder50000
    subfolder500001
    ...
    ...
    ...
    subfolder99999
    subfolder100000
```

Comment: Do you want to move subfolders which are serially numbered, like from 50001 t0 100000 or any random 50K subfolders?

Comment: randomly named folders

Comment: Try this: mv \`ls -d */| shuf| head -50000\` <Destination path> from the main folder

Answer (score 0):

As I can see all of your files have the same prefixes. You can use *mmv* to move file with prefix "subfolder5*" to one folder and the rest to another folder.
cheat-sheet: http://www.guckes.net/mmv/

Answer (score 0):

If you have folders with a similar name and only varying the numeral, try something like:

```
for I in $(seq 50000 100000);
do
   mv src/folder${I} dst/
done
```

You can digit line by line on linux.

src -> Source

dst -> Destiny

Command `seq` will rotate from start to finish, feeding I the current number, passing it to the `mv` command if you want verbose, you can add the `-v` in front of the `mv` command

Adapt the above command to your needs ;)